# Conditioning on a point in a continuous model

Tags: probability

By the definition of conditional probability, $P(A|B)$ is not defined when $P(B) = 0.$
Now, suppose the experiment consist of choosing a real number between $0 \& 1$.
Then the probability of choosing $0.5$ would be equal to $0$ as the size of our sample space is uncountably infinite.

I am thinking about the conditional probability of $0.5$ being chosen given that $0.5$ has already been chosen.
What will be the value of this probability: not defined or $1$?

Comment: See here: https://jmanton.wordpress.com/2012/06/28/sets-of-measure-zero-in-probability/

Answer (score 1):

Talking about $P(A|B)$ when $P(B)=0$ is not accurate enough.

To give a sense to $P(A|B)$, it is common to say that $B=\lim_{n}B_n$ where $B_{n+1}\subset B_n$ and $P(B_n)>0$. And to study $\lim_{n\to\infty}P(A|B_n)$.